# Find xml node value by having its sibling value using xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mappings>
    <enumMapping id="1" dsrName="yesno" emName="yesno_t">
        <valueMap>
            <dsrValue>Yes</dsrValue>
            <emValue>1</emValue>
        </valueMap>
        <valueMap>
            <dsrValue>No</dsrValue>
            <emValue>2</emValue>
        </valueMap>

    </enumMapping>
    <enumMapping id="2" dsrName="altRoutingOnConFailure" emName="Alternate_Routing_On_Connection_Failure_t">
        <valueMap>
            <dsrValue>Same Peer</dsrValue>
            <emValue>1</emValue>
        </valueMap>
        <valueMap>
            <dsrValue>Different Peer</dsrValue>
            <emValue>2</emValue>
        </valueMap>
        <valueMap>
            <dsrValue>Same Connection</dsrValue>
            <emValue>3</emValue>
        </valueMap>
    </enumMapping>
</mappings>
```

and Java code

```
public class Parser {
    Document doc;
    public Parser(String filename)
    {
        try{
            File inputFile = new File(filename);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    public void searchDsrEnum(String dsrName,String dsrValue)
    {

          XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
          XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
          try {
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("mappings/enumMapping[@dsrName=\""+dsrName+"\"]/valueMap/dsrValue");
            NodeList n1=(NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println(n1.getLength());


            //System.out.println(n1.);

        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

I need to find `emValue` field, with `dsrValue`=`Yes` and `enumMapping` attribute `dsrName=yesno` using `xpath`. 
I'm getting an error if I use

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("mappings/enumMapping[@dsrName=\""+dsrName+"\"]/valueMap//[dsrValue/text()=\""+dsrValue+"\"]/emValue");
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: I suspect the error was about invalid XPath expression, because this kind of expression is not valid XPath : `valueMap//[...]`. Maybe OP means `//valueMap[...]` ...

Comment: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.error(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.RelativeLocationPath(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.LocationPath(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.PathExpr(Unknown Source)
 at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible XPath expression :

```
/mappings/enumMapping[@dsrName='yesno']/valueMap[dsrValue='Yes']/emValue
```

**explanation :**

- `/mappings` : locate the root element `mappings`
- `/enumMapping[@dsrName='yesno']` : from the root element, find child element `enumMapping` where `dsrName` attribute value equals `"yesno"`
- `/valueMap[dsrValue='Yes']` : from such `enumMapping`, find child element `valueMap` where `dsrValue` child element equals `"Yes"`
- `/emValue` : from such `valueMap` return child element `emValue`

I also suggest to use single-quotes and `String.Format()` to clean up the code a bit :

```
String query = "/mappings/enumMapping[@dsrName='%s']/valueMap[dsrValue='%s']/emValue";
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(String.Format(query, dsrName, dsrValue));
```

Comment: dsrValue is a sibling of emValue...Not an attribute of valueMap

Comment: @ManishShambu sorry, typo on the explanation part